# Passing values while using php curl

Tags: php, php-curl

I am trying to request an API which has the following details:

**Request Headers:**

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
apikey: {{Your API Key}}
```

**Request Body:**

```
 "channel" : "chat",
"source" : "xxxxxxx",
"destination" : "xxxxxxxx"
"src.name":"DemoApp"
"message" : {
          "isHSM":"false",
        "type": "text",
        "text": "Hi John, how are you?"
}
```

my current code is as follows:

```
 $payload = [
    'channel' => $channel,
    'source' => $source,
    'destination'   => $destination,
    'message' => $message,
    'src.name' => $appname
    ];
    
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://apiurl/test",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($payload),
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "apikey:" . $apikey,
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    ),
    ));
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    if(curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I am not getting the message part correct in payload like adding **isHSM, type** etc..

My current code is:

```
$message = array(
            'isHSM' => true,
            'type' => "text",
            'text' => "This is a test"
            );
```

Requesting help on how to add the message payload in above curl request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an array into `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` to make it automatically `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Just remove the `http_build_query()` function and the appropriate header. The method to `POST` is also auto set.

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://apiurl/test",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "apikey:" . $apikey
    )
));
```

The message may be required to be converted into a JSON string.

```
$message = json_encode(array(
            'isHSM' => true,
            'type' => "text",
            'text' => "This is a test"
            ));
```